# Searching a Matrix and Returning Coordinates of a Value

Tags: java, matrix

I need to search a matrix for a certain value and return its coordinates; I have made the following script/function to do so. However, the function is not working because apparently when my if statement in `findIndexWithValue` runs it looks for a coordinate that is not in the array (to high). Could anyone help me out or give a more efficient method of doing what I am trying to do?

```
package main;

public class SolveMaze {

Pos start = new Pos(0,0);
Pos end = new Pos(0,0);

public static int getMazeWidth(int[][] maze){
    if (maze == null){
        System.out.println("Entered Maze Has Returned Null For Width");
        return 0;
    } else {
    return maze.length;

    }
}

public static int getMazeHeight(int[][] maze){
    if (maze == null){
        System.out.println("Entered Maze Has Returned Null For Height");
        return 0;
    } else {
    return maze[0].length;
    }
}




public static Pos findIndexWithValue(int[][] maze, int value){

    if (maze == null){
        System.out.println("Maze is NULL! (FindIndexWithValue)");
        return null;
    } else {
        for (int i1 = 0; i1 < getMazeWidth(maze) - 1; i1++){ //1
        int cordX = 0;
        int cordY = 0;
        cordY = 0;

            for (int i2 = 0; i2 < getMazeHeight(maze) - 1; i2++){ //9
                if (maze[cordX][cordY] == value){
                    Pos returnPos = new Pos(cordX, cordY);
                    return returnPos;
                }
                cordY++;
            }
            cordX++;

        }
    }
    System.out.println("The Value You Are Looking For is not Present (findIndexWithValue)");
    return null;
}


}
```

and the main class is:

```
package main;

public class MazeSolver {

final static int[][] maze = {
    {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
    {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
    {-1, 1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
    {-1, 0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
    {-1, 0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
    {-1, 0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
    {-1, 0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
    {-1, 0,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
    {-1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1,-1},
    {-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1,-1},
    };

public static void main(String args[]){

Pos test = new Pos(0,0);
test = SolveMaze.findIndexWithValue(maze, 1);
System.out.println(test.getX() + " " + test.getY());


}

}
```

Comment: When you post a question about an error message, it helps to also post the stack trace containing the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing weird things in your for-for loop :-)

This should fix it:

```
public static Pos findIndexWithValue(int[][] maze, int value) {

    if (maze == null) {
        System.out.println("Maze is NULL! (FindIndexWithValue)");
        return null;
    } else {
        for (int x = 0; x < getMazeWidth(maze); x++) {
            for (int y = 0; y < getMazeHeight(maze); y++) {
                if (maze[x][y] == value) {
                    Pos returnPos = new Pos(x, y);
                    return returnPos;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("The Value You Are Looking For is not Present (findIndexWithValue)");
    return null;
}
```

Also, just a tip: NEVER name your variables i1 or i2. Whoever reads your code will have a hard time understanding it.